# Can you see the total number of sellable collectables you have found?

Tags: hollow-knight

When you sell a Wanderer's Journals, Hallownest Seal, etc; it is removed from your inventory as if you never had it. But given that there are a finite number of these items to find in the world; I would want to make sure I find them all as part of my playthrough. Is there any place in the game that tells you how many you have found, or how many you have left to find? Or do you just have to make sure you remember how many you have sold so far?

Answer (score 2):

In the game there is no indication of how many of this relics that we have sold to relic seeker Lemm. From my playthrough I just rely on the hollowknight.fandom.com wiki to view the locations of the relic that I don't remember finding and use that as an indication of how many relics I am missing. But yeah it would be much better if there was a counter to indicate this which would be a minor quality of life change but would be helpful for people looking to collect all of the relics.